# Aws Elastic Beanstalk deploy Akka application

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, sbt, akka

I have a simple akka Http Server:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{ContentTypes, HttpEntity}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.HttpApp
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.settings.ServerSettings
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object MinimalHttpServer extends HttpApp {
  def route =
    pathPrefix("v1") {
      path("subscribe" / Segment) { id =>
        get {
          complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, s"<h1>Hello $id from Akka Http!</h1>"))
        } ~
        post {
          entity(as[String]) { entity =>
            complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, s"<b>Thanks $id for posting your message <i>$entity</i></b>"))
          }
        }
      }
    }
}

object MinimalHttpServerApplication extends App {
  MinimalHttpServer.startServer("localhost", 8088, ServerSettings(ConfigFactory.load))
}
```

I use Sbt native Packager to build an universal zip. When I deploy my application to Aws Elastic Beanstalk, I receive this error:

[Instance: i-0a846978718d54d76] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...xml_2.11-1.0.5.jar Unable to launch application as the source bundle does not contain either a file named application.jar or a Procfile. Unable to launch application as the source bundle does not contain either a file named application.jar or a Procfile. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/01_configure_application.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

Any Ideas? Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

It appears AWS Elastic Beanstalk expects your .zip to contain either a file named `application.jar` or a Procfile, and the zip created by `sbt-native-packager` does not look like that.

It appears `sbt-native-packager` does not have support for the format Elastic Beanstalk expects, though [GitHub issue 632](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/632) shows some work done in that direction.